# Сгрупировать массив и очистить от null. PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет, Есть вот такой массив:

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => null
    "group" => null
    "alias" => null
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Река"
    "group" => "Природа"
    "alias" => "river"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => null
    "group" => null
    "alias" => null
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => null
    "group" => null
    "alias" => null
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => null
    "group" => null
    "alias" => null
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Тигр"
    "group" => "Животные"
    "alias" => "tiger"
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => null
    "group" => null
    "alias" => null
  ]
  7 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Медведи"
    "group" => "Животные"
    "alias" => "bears"
  ]
  8 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Медведи"
    "group" => "Животные"
    "alias" => "bears"
  ]
  9 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => null
    "group" => null
    "alias" => null
  ]
]
```

Как мне из такого массива получить вот такой?

```
5 => array:1 [▼
   "groups" => "Животные"
      1 => array:2 [▼
           1 => array:2 [▼
                "name" => "Тигр"
                "alias" => "tiger"
                ]
           2 => array:2 [▼
                "name" => "Медведи"
                "alias" => "bears"
                ]
      "groups" => "Природа"
                1 => array:1 [▼
                   1 => array:2 [▼
                   "name" => "Река"
                    "alias" => "river"
                ]
  ]
```

Для того что бы потом в шаблоне выводить данные в таком виде:

```
Животные:
1) Тигр
2) Медведи
Природа:
1) Река
```

Comment: Двойным циклом, foreach например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$groups = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
    if ( !empty($item['name']) ) {
        $groups['groups'][$item['group']][] = [
            'name'  =>  $item['name'],
            'alias' =>  $item['alias']
        ];  
        $groups['groups'][$item['group']] = array_unique($groups['groups'][$item['group']], SORT_REGULAR);
    }     
}

var_dump($groups);
```

Собираются уникальные группы с массива, и в дальнейшем простой вывод

```
foreach ($groups['groups'] as $gName => $gItems) {
    echo $gName . ': ' . implode(', ', array_column($gItems, 'name')) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$arrd=array(
  "0" => array(
    "name" => null,
    "group" => null,
    "alias" => null
  ),
  "1" => array(
    "name" => "Река",
    "group" => "Природа",
    "alias" => "river"
  ),
  "2" => array(
    "name" => null,
    "group" => null,
    "alias" => null
  ),
  "3" => array(
    "name" => null,
    "group" => null,
    "alias" => null
  ),
  "4" => array(
    "name" => null,
    "group" => null,
    "alias" => null
  ),
  "5" => array(
    "name" => "Тигр",
    "group" => "Животные",
    "alias" => "tiger"
  ),
  "6" => array(
    "name" => null,
    "group" => null,
    "alias" => null
  ),
  "7" => array(
     "name" => "Медведи",
    "group" => "Животные",
    "alias" => "bears"
  ),
  "8" => array(
    "name" => "Медведи",
    "group" => "Животные",
    "alias" => "bears"
  ),
  "9" => array(
    "name" => null,
    "group" => null,
    "alias" => null
  )
);



foreach ($arrd as $key => $value) {
    # code..
if(!$value["group"]==null or !$value["group"]==''){
    

    # code...
if ($value["group"]=="Животные") {


$gr1[]=array("name" => $value["name"], "alias"=>$value["alias"]);
$grs["Животные"]=array_unique($gr1, SORT_REGULAR);

}elseif($value["group"]=="Природа"){

    # code...

$gr2[]=array("name" => $value["name"], "alias"=>$value["alias"]);
$grp["Природа"]=array_unique($gr2, SORT_REGULAR);

}

}

}


$gr=array_merge($grs, $grp);
print_r($gr);

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у вас проверка if ($value["group"]=="Животные") мне не подходит, т.к данные не известно какие будут, group может быть так же и "Люди"

Comment: унифицируй не чего сложного нет

Comment: уже написали как правильно